# How to boot into the windows after HDD change and reset of bios and MBR/GPT boot tables?

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, bios, gpt

First of all let me mention the configuration of the PC:

It is veeeery old PC like 12 years.

There is already really new (5 months ago) SSD disk (250GB) which was working suprisingly perfectly with Windows 10 and 4GB RAM separated in 1GB parts in each slots (I know I know ...) so the RAM is like 1x1x1x1 in total of 4GB. It is Office PC running maximum of browser and 5 program installed in total so it was ok for a long time. There is like zero possibility to install or load anything from USB. Only CD (not even DVD) as it lods to RAM and it freezes during loading (maybe not enough RAM).

We tried to change different HDD (2TB) which was faulted for another 2TB one. But due to that we also restarted BIOS by accident and change the positions of the disk in SATA slots. It briefly said something like "Load configuration" or "restore defaults" in 5,4,3,2, and before we could do anthing it changed to default by its own during startup making the SSD disk not boot into windows now saying there is no system please insert system disk.

We were able to go into Linux live CD and restore GTP table it seems but the partition types and active partitions are not set like in the picture:
[SSD system disk 250 GB][1]

Everything is there as you can see - we just need to boot into it somehow again. It says now "no active partition". I think the partition types are also not correct (which we can change in linux live CD)

How can we boot into the fully working and installed Windows which was working perfectly and only switching not important (external) disk (and maybe BIOS) made it unusable?

Thank you all for any help.

The BIOS says now the disks use IDE not SATA but this can be changed if needed (BIOS from 2007)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vfeo.jpg

Comment: Hopefully someone else will have better suggestions but I bet the drive mode changed when it "switched defaults".  After the drive mode changed, you made PHYSICAL changes to the partition scheme.  I myself would suggest starting over with nothing but the SSD plugged in.  After everything is working plug in other drives.  You probably should not be using GPT.. just MBR.  2007 is the line when UEFI became a standard and your firmware might very well be questionable unless in legacy mode.

Comment: I already have only one disk plugged in as seen in the picture - it is one disk with two partitions. I tried to fix it with MBR fix but then the system said it has GPT so it switched to GPT from MBR in the Linux LILO and GDISK. So I made that. According to me there is a problem now with the "types" and the fact that it has no active partition for boot. I tried to make it work with MBR - in linux i did LILO fix of MBR and made active partition but it did not work for me. Now I am trying GPT but I am not sure how to make partition active for boot and how to set proper type of the partitions.

Comment: BTW, 4gb is enough to do *almost* anything.  That has nothing to do with your problem.  I would first go back into your firmware settings.. if there is a choice, set to Legacy mode.  Then boot your Linux install media.. (or a live disk) choose custom disk.. wipe EVERYTHING.. Then back up to the partitioning install screen and let Linux choose the best partition layout.  I myself prefer a custom layout.. but that is another story.. ;)  GOOD LUCK.  There are many partition experts here.  Just keep asking questions.